# Trying to export shapefile attributetable to JSON using GeoPandas without the geometry

Tags: python, shapefile, geojson, geopandas

I am using GeoPandas' read_file function to read a shapefile
and to_file function to save to GeoJSON.
This is working fast and good.

But I need to save only the attribute table without the geometry
or with empty geometry.

How can I do that?

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import fiona


def main():
filepath = "D:\\DATA\layers1\\TTL_TRANSPORT.shp"
destination = "D:\\DATA\\jsonfiles\sample.json"

gdf = gpd.read_file(filepath)

df = pd.DataFrame(gdf)
columns_without_geom = gdf.columns

print( columns_without_geom)

if 'geometry' in columns_without_geom:
   columns_without_geom.drop('geometry')

gdf = gdf[columns_without_geom]
df = pd.DataFrame(gdf)
df.to_json(destination)
df.to_json(destination)
```

Answer (score 5):

GeoPandas is an addon to Pandas where a `geometry` column has special meaning and writing output writes geospatial file formats. If you want to export just the non-spatial data, the easiest way would be to create a plain Pandas DataFrame from your GeoDataframe, so the geometry column loses its special meaning, and then remove it.

To do so in one "step":

```
df = pd.DataFrame(gdf).drop(columns="geometry")
```

Then you can use the resulting DataFrame's `to_json()` as intended.

```
df.to_json(destination)
```

Answer (score 0):

If needed, you can convert your dataframe to pandas dataframe and save it with:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

so something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(gdf)
df.to_json(output)
```

You might have to select columns without geometry.

```
columns_without_geom = gdf.columns
if 'geometry' in columns_without_geom: 
     columns_without_geom.remove('geometry')

gdf = gdf[columns_without_geom]
df = pd.DataFrame(gdf)
df.to_json(output)
```

Comment: hi jan thanks for your reply i am getting this error " module 'geopandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame' "

Comment: now i am getting this error "columns_without_geom.remove('geometry')
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'remove' "

Comment: ```pandas.Index``` are very similar to python sets, you should use ```.difference(['geometry'])```. Since set difference operation supports non-overlapping sets, you can avoid the if and instead use ```gdf = gdf.loc[:,gdf.columns.difference(['geometry'])]```

Comment: hola Javier i am getting this error "No geometry data set yet (expected in column 'geometry'.)" while  gdf.to_file

Comment: Now the error is, you removed geometry column. So you have to cast it to pandas dataframe as in my comment and save it via pandas and not geopandas, since it does not have geometry.

Comment: Hi Jan your advice did solve the previous error but now I have two new problems1. the json structure of the original shape is all messed up 2.unicode text that was in the shape is coming out as Gibberish.  :)